# Which is the fastest way of converting an Object to a stream of Bytes in Java?

Tags: java, performance, object, serialization, unsafe

I have an object which I want to convert into a stream of bytes and then to operate on it. I don't want to serialise the object, but just to convert it. I have read this [article](http://mechanical-sympathy.blogspot.de/2012/07/native-cc-like-performance-for-java.html), where Java Unsafe class is used and the conversion is very fast. However, is there any other fast solution for this?

Comment: Converting an object to a stream of bytes *is* serializing it. You may not want to use "the default Java binary serialization mechanism" but you're still serializing. What do you want to do with the bytes afterwards? Do you need to be able to reconstitute the object later? Within the same VM? In a different VM? It would really help if you'd give more context.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question.  Conversion to a stream of bytes is more or less the definition of serialization.

Comment: Please provide your codes

Comment: This depends very much on your requirements. What do you want to do with the bytes? Send them to another machine? Can the object contain references to other objects? ...

Comment: Dear @JonSkeet, what I want to do is to construct a kind of arrayList that will manipulate the stream of bytes. I was thinking to try to do a C++ style list where objects are stored contigously in the memory. I am just experimenting with it and I would like to know if this is possible or not. However, if the cost of converting the Object to a stream of bytes is big, there is no point in what I am trying to do. Thanks for your reply. Moreover, I don't care about portability but only for the current JVM.

Comment: But *why* are you trying to do this? It sounds like it almost certainly *is* pointless - are you really just trying to get locality of usage in memory? If so, I would expect the overheads of this to be far worse than the benefits. You'll be duplicating the data for *all* the objects in the graph, because otherwise you've got no way of representing references. (Remember that objects can move around in memory, get garbage collected etc.)

Comment: I was wondering if we can have a collection in Java by using Unsafe  with performance similar to C++. More specifically, I was wondering if there can be benefits if the data of this collection were accessed directly and not through references. Of course this is just a use case with limited functions. However, now I understand that the drawbacks are too many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of libraries in development to do what you suggest.  I believe all of them are discussed on this forum. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mechanical-sympathy which may also have many topics which may interest you.

In short you can do it using Unsafe, or a library which uses it. In fact I have one of my own, but again it is in development.

For the effort involved this will only make much of a difference if you have many GB of data.  At this point the reduce GC times and reduced size of the heap are the main advantages, on saving a single de-reference.

Answer (score 2):

Fast Convertion is possible. You can use GSON lib. then get it to json string. Use the string as per your requirement. Hope this helps.